# How to use argument-resolvers using annotation in Spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I would like to use `argument-resolvers` in Spring boot. How do I go about it?
It is done in XML as below.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <bean class="nl.t42.spring31.ValidatingRequestBodyMethodArgumentResolver"/>
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: Probably if you just register it as bean, it will be handled automatically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See [here](http://www.robinhowlett.com/blog/2013/02/13/spring-app-migration-from-xml-to-java-based-config/)

You can do:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
      // equivalent to <mvc:argument-resolvers>
  }


  @Override
  public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
      // equivalent to <mvc:message-converters>
  }
}
```

`@EnableWebMvc` will override the Boot defaults, you may want to skip it.

Comment: Option 1 does not help

Comment: Very important:"@EnableWebMvc will override the Boot defaults, you may want to skip it." Actually in Spring Boot this annotation should not be present. It can cause unexcepted behavior.

Comment: It is important to take into account the @bogdan.rusu comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had i same issue with **Datatables** when i want to convert my **spring mvc** to **spring boot** and **useWebMvcConfigurerAdapter**, so i need to convert my dispatcher servlet xml to java bean config, i had done like this :

From dispatcher.servlet.xml:

```
       <mvc:argument-resolvers>
         <bean 
 class="com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.spring3.ajax.DatatablesCriteriasMethodArgu 
        mentResolver"/>
     </mvc:argument-resolvers>
```

to java bean config :

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
            // equivalent to <mvc:argument-resolvers>
            argumentResolvers.add(resolver());
        }


        private HandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver() {
            return new com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.spring3.ajax.DatatablesCriteriasMethodArgumentResolver();
        }
    }
```