# Get a message converter bean in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to instantiate a resolver from `spring-cloud-aws-messaging`, specifically the `NotificationMessageArgumentResolver`. The problem is that it takes a `MessageConvertor` as an argument. So, this is what I have so far:

```
private NotificationMessageArgumentResolver notificationMessageArgumentResolver() {
    new NotificationMessageArgumentResolver(this.messageConvertor);
}
```

To get the `messageConvertor`, I have tried:

```
@Autowired
public MvcConfig(MessageConvertor messageConvertor) {}

@Autowired
public MvcConfig(MappingJackson2MessageConverter messageConvertor) {}
```

but I get the same error either ways `no bean found`. The documentation is simply asking to use the XML:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
<mvc:argument-resolvers>
    <ref bean="notificationResolver" />
</mvc:argument-resolvers>
```

```
<aws-messaging:notification-argument-resolver id="notificationResolver" />
```

Which, according to the doc

> registers three argument resolvers: `NotificationStatusHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`, `NotificationMessageHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`, and `NotificationSubjectHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`.

So, following the answer from [How to use argument-resolvers using annotation in Spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175125/how-to-use-argument-resolvers-using-annotation-in-spring-boot), I am able to get 2 of the 3 beans added, as they don't need any beans I cannot access, however I am not able to instantiate `NotificationMessageArgumentResolver` due to the lack of a `MessageConvertor`. I am expecting all my messages to come purely in JSON, so I do know exactly which `MessageConvertor` to use, which is the default one for JSON that ships with Spring Boot.

**EDIT**

The entire file, if anyone is interested: http://pastebin.com/tM471AEv

Comment: Why are you trying to use the `NotificationMessageArgumentResolver`? That is for messaging not for mvc stuff. Are you sure you don't need the `NotificationMessageHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` instead? And if so instead of configuring 3 individual beans use the `NotificationHandlerMethodArgumentResolverFactoryBean` instead which registers them for you.

Comment: Now, ain't I a silly little idiot? Thank you so much! I guess using an IDE does not mean that I can stop reading the auto-complete code. If you put this as an answer, I'll select it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you really need the [`NotificationMessageArgumentResolver`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/master/spring-cloud-aws-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/support/NotificationMessageArgumentResolver.java#L24) as that is intended to be used when using messaging. As you can see it implements the `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` from the `org.springframework.messaging` package.

I suspect that you want to use the [`NotificationMessageHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/master/spring-cloud-aws-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/endpoint/NotificationMessageHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java) instead. Which is the `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` for use with the web instead of messaging. Which is also registered when using `<aws-messaging:notification-argument-resolver id="notificationResolver" />`

I would also suggest to use the [`NotificationHandlerMethodArgumentResolverFactoryBean`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/master/spring-cloud-aws-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/endpoint/config/NotificationHandlerMethodArgumentResolverFactoryBean.java) instead of 3 individual beans as that is also the class that is used internally by the namespace and annotation driven configuration.

Your configuration would look something like this.

```
@Bean
public NotificationHandlerMethodArgumentResolverFactoryBean notificationHandlerMethodArgumentResolverFactoryBean() {
    return new NotificationHandlerMethodArgumentResolverFactoryBean();
}

@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    argumentResolvers.add(notificationHandlerMethodArgumentResolverFactoryBean.getObject());
}
```